# Finding li element by text inside - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, dom, element

I have been trying to find a way to click a specific li element by using the text inside, however, whatever I try seems to not be finding the element.

The HTML is;

`<ul class="shoes-sizen-mp" id="ul_top_hypers" style="overflow: auto;">`

```
<li id="li_284" onclick="return select_size('284')"><a class="a_top_hypers">  3.5  <span style="display: none">,</span><br>   35.5<br></a></li>
```

```
<li id="li_285" onclick="return select_size('285')"><a class="a_top_hypers">  4  <span style="display: none">,</span><br>   36<br></a></li>
```

This is part of a list where you can select your size (such as 3.5,4,4.5,5). I want to be able to click the specific one by using the text such as 3.5, for example.

*Edit*

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//ul[@id='ul_top_hypers' and starts-with(@id, 'li_'][contains(text(),'{user_shoe_size}')]").click()
sleep(20)
```

Above is one of the many things I have tried to locate the element, but nothing just yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on dynamic induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following xpath.

```
def click_size(size):
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='shoes-sizen-mp']//li[contains(.,'{}')]".format(size)))).click()

click_size("3.5")
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Worked a charm. Thanks a lot mate.